# Javascript alert not working with global variale

Tags: javascript

i would appreciate if someone can tell me why this script only works with a local variable and not with a global variable. I would think that a global variables should work always.
I just want to understand why this is not working....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>`enter code here`
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <button id="submit" onclick="calculate()">CALCULATE</button>
    
    
    </body>
    
    
    
    
    //NOT WORKING WITH GLOBAL VARIABLE
    <script>
    
    var numbers = document.getElementById("number").value;
    
    function calculate(){
        alert(numbers);
    }
    
    </script>
    
    
    
    //WORKING WITH LOCAL VARIABLE
    <script>
    
    
    function calculate(){
    
    var numbers = document.getElementById("number").value;
    
        alert(numbers);
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: The first one fills the numbers variable on load, which by then is probably undefined or empty. When you hit calculate, it takes that value and alerts it. In the second case it gets the value on demand, that's why you get the updated value.

Comment: that sounds logical thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @MauriceNino  How can i close the post and mark this as solved?

Comment: better just delete it and save your karma tbh. if you dont want that, just accept the answer I have posted, that marks it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

It won't work until you trigger `calculate()`. Cause once the page gets loaded the `numbers` variable is also stored undefined data.

Since you're taking the input after the page loading, you've to initiate the `number` variable inside the `calcualte()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The first one fills the numbers variable on load, which by then is probably undefined or empty. When you hit calculate, it takes that value and alerts it. In the second case it gets the value on demand, that's why you get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
// value is set with the default value at load which is ""
var numbers = document.getElementById("number").value;
console.log(numbers);
function calculate() {
    numbers = document.getElementById("number").value;
    alert(numbers);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="number" value="initial">
    <button id="submit" onclick="calculate()">CALCULATE</button>
</body>

</html>
```